# Geometry question: Find the area of blue-shared area inside this isosceles

Tags: contest-math, euclidean-geometry, recreational-mathematics, plane-geometry

See below, looks a bit interesting, but I cannot find a solution.

I think a starting point might be the similarity of the lower white triangle and the larger triangle composed of lower blue, pink, and lower right triangle though..

[image]

Comment: Maybe it helps that I got 96 and 73.5 just playing with Geogebra.

Comment: @garondal: Confirmed. ... Interestingly, the target area is generally entangled in a messy-looking cubic relation with the square areas. The specific areas $49$ and $256$ happen to create a linear factor that yields the result you found.

Comment: @Blue might to elaborate on the "messy looking cubic relation"?

Comment: @Vendetta: Since you asked... If $a\leq b$ are the sides of the squares, and $t$ is the total target area, then $$\begin{align} 0&=8t^3\\ &+4t^2(a-b)(a-2b)\\ &-2t\phantom{^2}(a^2+b^2)(a^2+6ab-b^2)\\
&-\phantom{2}a\;(a-b)(a^4+2a^3b-2a^2b^2-2ab^3-3b^4)\end{align}$$ For $a=7$, $b=16$, this reduces to $(2t-339)(4t^2+1128t+49371)=0$, so that $t=169.5=96+73.5$. If the vertex angle is $2\theta$, then the specific $a$ and $b$ yield $\tan\theta=1/3$ and $\tan2\theta=3/4$ (so there's a connection to the $3$-$4$-$5$ triangle). I've been looking for deeper "meaning" here, but haven't (yet) found it.

Comment: @Vendetta: What's the source of this problem? And what's the target audience? This information could give an idea of the level of sophistication expected in a solution.

Comment: @Blue my niece gave me. He is in middle school. He knows trigonometry. So I think most elementary solutions are fair game.

Comment: @Blue can you elaborate more on that giant cubic expression? Not even sure how you got it after you wrote it out. You might as well put it as an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution without trig, but always leading to a cubic equation.

Notice first of all that if you have a square inscribed into a right triangle, with the right angle in common, then the side of the square is equal to the product of the legs of the triangle, divided by their sum (this can be easily proved using triangle similarity).

Let now $a=AD$, $b=BD$ and $c=CD$ (see figure below). By the above observation we get then two equations:

$$
ab=7(a+b),\quad bc=16(b+c).
$$
As $AC=BC$ we also have:
$$
(a+c)^2=b^2+c^2,
\quad\text{that is:}\quad
2ac=b^2-a^2.
$$
From the last equation we get:
$$
c={b^2-a^2\over2a}.
$$
Plugging that into the second equation we obtain:
$$
(b-16)(b^2-a^2)=32ab=32\cdot7(a+b)
$$
and we can factor out $(a+b)$ to find
$$
a=b-{224\over b-16}.
$$
Inserting that into the first equation finally leads to a cubic equation for $b$:
$$
b^3-30b^2+1568=0.
$$
Trying the divisors of $1568=2^5\cdot7^2$ greater than $16$ we can find that $b=28$ is a solution: factoring leads then to a quadratic equation whose solutions can be discarded (one is negative and the other is less than $16$).

Hence $b=28$ is the only solution and from that the requested area can be easily computed.

[image]

Comment: Doing something similar I ended up with $$-x^3-18x^2+192x+2016=0$$ and the correct solution $$x=12.$$ But this seems too tedious.

Comment: The fact you stated in the start is more easily proved by areas: Let the square have vertex $V$ on the left side of the isoceles triangles then $(CD)(BD)=(BD)s+(CD)s=(BD+CD)s$ where s is the side length of the square

Comment: @garondal Indeed, it would be nice to have a simpler solution. But all answers seen so far involve a cubic equation, hence I'm not optimistic.

Comment: Hello. I'm from the future. Could you tell me what tool/software you used to draw the triangle?

Comment: @user516076 I used GeoGebra Classic (version 4, if you manage to find it, or version 5).

Answer (score 1):

Expanding-upon a comment, as requested.

[image]

Let the triangle have vertex angle $2\theta$, let $a\leq b$ be the sides of the squares, and let $t$ denote the target area. We immediately find

$$\begin{align}
a+a\cot\theta = |PQ| = b+b\tan2\theta \tag{1} \\
t = \frac12\cdot a\cdot a\cot\theta + \frac12\cdot b \cdot b\tan2\theta \tag{2}
\end{align}$$

From here, "all we have to do" is eliminate $\theta$ from $(1)$ and $(2)$. One way to do that here is first to treat the equations as a linear system in $\cot\theta$ and $\tan2\theta$; solving gives

$$\cot\theta = \frac{2t-b(a-b)}{a (a + b)} \qquad 
\tan2\theta = \frac{2t+a(a-b)}{b (a + b)} \tag{3}$$

Reciprocating $\cot\theta$ into $\tan\theta$, and substituting into the double-angle identity $\tan2\theta=2\tan\theta/(1-\tan^2\theta)$, and "simplifying" gives this relation among $t$, $a$, and $b$:

$$\begin{align}
0 
&= 8 t^3 \\
&+ 4 t^2 (a - b)(a - 2 b)  \\
&- 2 t\phantom{^2}(a^2 + b^2)(a^2 + 6 a b - b^2)  \\
&- \phantom{2}a (a - b) (a^4 + 2 a^3 b - 2 a^2 b^2 - 2 a b^3 - 3 b^4) 
\end{align} \tag{$\star$}$$

In the particular case of $a=7$ and $b=16$, $(\star)$ reduces into a factorable form and we have
$$(2t-339) (4t^2+1128t+49371) = 0 \quad\to\quad t = \frac{339}{2} \tag{$\star$'}$$
which gives our answer. $\square$

---

As an alternative to the above approach with $(3)$ we could re-write $(1)$  in terms of $\tan\theta$ alone:

$$(a-b)\tan^3\theta + (a+2b)\tan^2\theta-(a-b)\tan\theta-a=0 \tag{4}$$

For $a=7$ and $b=16$, this reduces to
$$(3\tan\theta-1) (3\tan^2\theta-12\tan\theta-7) =0 \tag{5}$$
Therefore (casually ignoring a positive root of the second factor),
$$\tan\theta = \frac13\qquad\to\qquad\tan2\theta=\frac{3}{4}\qquad\stackrel{\text{by (1)}}{\to}\qquad t = \frac{339}{2}\tag{6}$$

(See the edit history that also rewrites $(2)$ in terms of $\tan\theta$ alone before eliminating $\tan\theta$ from the system to get $(\star)$.)

An advantage of this approach is that $(4)$ is "more-immediate" to factor. Also, we see explicitly that $\tan\theta$ and $\tan2\theta$ are nice values. Knowing $\tan\theta=1/3$ facilitates drawing an accurate figure.

More importantly, $\tan2\theta=3/4$ reveals a non-obvious connection to the $3$-$4$-$5$ triangle. I can't help thinking that there's a clever way to detect and exploit it.

---

Yet-another way to proceed is to seek the distance $p:=|PQ|$.  ([@Aretino's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3736252/409) uses another approach to this.) Clearly,
$$\tan\theta = \frac{a}{p-a} \quad \tan2\theta=\frac{p-b}{b} \qquad\stackrel{\text{dbl ang}}{\to}\qquad p^3 - p^2(2 a + b) + 2 a^2 b  =0 \tag{7}$$
(The nicest cubic yet!) For $a=7$ and $b=16$, this reduces to
$$(p-28) (p^2-2p-56)=0 \quad\to\quad p = 28 \tag{8}$$
from which the result follows thusly:
$$t = \frac12a(p-a)+\frac12b(p-b) = \cdots = \frac{339}{2} \tag{9}$$
This solution seems like it might be the most accessible to middle-schoolers, although it, too, ignores the underlying $3$-$4$-$5$ triangle. (Perhaps I'm over-estimating the significance of that triangle!)

Comment: By similar triangles, if we let the segment of the right side of the triangle above b=16 be $\beta$, and the segment on the left of the lower side b=16 be $\alpha$, then $\alpha\beta=256$. Kind of peculiar